# Set locale in angular2-material-datepicker

Tags: angular, typescript, localization, locale, datetimepicker

I am trying to set locale for angular2-material-datepicker. 
I have gone through many posts which refer [$mdDateLocaleProvider](https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.9/api/service/$mdDateLocaleProvider). But I do not know how to incorporate this using typescript. We are developing our project using Angular2.

Answer (score 5):

Editing the app.module.ts doesn't provide locale changes during runtime. After some debugging and this [ticket](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5041) I figured out that this works

```
export class AppComponent {

constructor(private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>) {
   dateAdapter.setLocale('de');
}
```

You can certainly do that in any other component you use for localization.

Answer (score 4):

Try to add

```
{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: "en-GB" }
```

to your provider, in app.module.

Comment: I don't think it works... yet... Apparently that is going to work on beta 9+ https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/datepicker/datepicker.md

Comment: yes this works on higher version. Anyways I have switched to higher version date picker

Comment: Did you get it to work at all? I'm confused, the documentation says very little

Answer (score 4):

You should install both `@angular/material-moment-adapter` and `moment` in your project!
Execute the following commands in your project directory:

```
npm install @angular/material-moment-adapter
npm install moment
```

Then you need to update your `app.module.ts` as followed if you want set locale globally for your app:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS, MomentDateAdapter} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';

/** @title Datepicker with different locale */
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [],
  entryComponents: [],
  providers: [
    // The locale would typically be provided on the root module of your application. We do it at
    // the component level here, due to limitations of our example generation script.
    {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'ja-JP'},

    // `MomentDateAdapter` and `MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS` can be automatically provided by importing
    // `MatMomentDateModule` in your applications root module. We provide it at the component level
    // here, due to limitations of our example generation script.
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private adapter: DateAdapter<any>) {}

  setDateAdapterLocale(localeString: string): void {
    this.dateAdapter.setLocale(localeString);
  }
}
```

Reference:
1. [Datepicker | Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)
2. [Moment | Github](https://github.com/moment/moment)
3. [@angular/material-moment-adapter | npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/material-moment-adapter)

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but in case someone still needs, the following post shows how to set it:

https://medium.com/@kristinahertmann/multi-language-date-formats-with-angular-material-b8598415d117

in resume would be this:

```
constructor(private translate: TranslateService, private dateAdapter: DateAdapter<Date>) {}

useLanguage(language: Languages): void{
   this.translate.use(language);
   this.dateAdapter.setLocale(language);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to app.module.ts providers:

```
{provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'de-DE'}
```